# How to create Isolated test environment

Tags: vlan, vmware-vcenter

I am very new to the VMware world. We have VMWare vCenter 4 in the production environment but we have created multiple VLAN through Cisco Switch. I want know, how I can create an isolated test environment for software testing purpose only, so anything will happen in that test vLan will not make trouble in the production environment.
"Host-only networking" is the solution or there is a better way to achieve this result?
My requirements
A. Hosts should be able to access Internet and a Network Share drive but not Production network
B. Hosts should connect each other inside the Virtual LAN
C. I should be able to take automatic or periodic backup or snapshoot and deploy snapshot when necessary.

Whatever your answer is, please give me steps, how to do, if possible.
If I need to purchase anything, I am ready to do but I don't want to spend big money.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare has a product called Lab Manager that might be worth a look at

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid i can't give you a step-by-step guide, but it seems you already have the knowledge you need. just setup a new vlan for your testing environment and make sure there is no routing between production and testing.

the next better step would be to setup the testing environment on there own switches to prevent the production switch from breaking by floods of packets from the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Vmware has also a host-only network, where only host inside vmware can comunicate with each other.

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html